# How can I backup my blogspot.com hosted blog?

Tags: blog, backup, blogger

I have a blog hosted on blogspot.com, and I'd like to back it up.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

There is NO way that I know of to do a complete backup (defined as an off-line copy that you can restore from).

You can export your post and comments via Settings > Basic > Export Blog - and this will let you re-import those posts and comments into the same or another (Blogger) blog.

You can save your template via Design > Edit HTML > Download full template - and this will let you re-import the template as it was.

You can make an off-line copy using something like HHTrack:  This is useful if you need to show people you blog off-line - but you cannot restore from it.   Also, there are some components (Google Maps for certain, I'm not sure about others) that the copy will have the links to, but not the component (meaning it won't work off-line).

I don't know any way to backup the contents/settings of your gadgets   (your blog-template knows where the widgets go and what type they are, but does not appear to know what settings they have).

Answer (score 4):

You can [export your blog](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416) as an XML file.

> To export your blog, simply click Export Blog from the Settings | Basic tab.

Answer (score 2):

i would use a python (or xyz) script and [fetch the content via the API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#RetrievingWithoutQuery):

```
def PrintAllPosts(blogger_service, blog_id):
  feed = blogger_service.GetFeed('/feeds/' + blog_id + '/posts/default')

  print feed.title.text
  for entry in feed.entry:
    print "\t" + entry.title.text
    print "\t" + entry.content.text
    print "\t" + entry.updated.text
  print
```

run that via cron or whatever periodic mechanism is available.

Comment: That's nice, but what about the uploaded images / documents?

Comment: there are multiple ways: you host such images (then grab them from there) OR you just press "upload". then these images will be hosted by picasa .. which is essentially ANOTHER "blog" and you can fetch these images just like you fetch the posts of your blog.